# How to send email to different recipient with a different set of data in SSIS or by SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis, ssis-2008

Please suggest me how to achieved this:

[image: emails_data]

The other table having set of data which I need to send:

[image: set_Of_Data]

Now by using SSIS we have to send the set of data to that email. In production I'm having 135 emails and have send them a separate data which contain their set of area.

@pp@gmial.cpm will get only data where subject is maths.

I have no idea to create variable of how to pass variable.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Gunna repeat a comment I made earlier today: *You'll need to use an Execute T-SQL task to input the data into an object variable, and then loop through the data with a For each Container. SSIS, however, doesn't support HTML emails, so unless you're happy with plain text then doing this sort of task in SQL Server with a `CURSOR`, or using a actual mail merge application would be a better option.*

Comment: Also, are you *really* still using BIDS? Support for the version you have tagged ended well over a year ago; it's past time you went through an upgrade cycle now.

Comment: can you please help me with creating variable

Answer (score 0):

I use this method a lot for sending emails:

```
    public static void SendEmail(List<string> to, string subject, string body,  string filepathName = null)
    {
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            string from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"];

            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("your email server"); 

            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            foreach(string t in to)
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(t));

            mail.Subject = subject;

            mail.ReplyToList.Add("your reply to email");
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.Bcc.Add("enter your email if you want to be copied");

            if (filepathName != null)
            {
                Attachment file;
                file = new Attachment(filepathName);
                mail.Attachments.Add(file);
            }

            SmtpServer.Port = 2525; //this is unique to you
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"]);


            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            
        }
    }
```

This won't completely solve your problem but will give you option of sending HTML emails straight from SSIS Script task.

You won't be able to use configuration manager, you will need to "hard code" that.